# How to fix dependency conflict?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Where's the conflict, how to fix it, and to find in the future the source of conflict?

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
>   > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is
>   >     available at
>   >     https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/)
>   >     or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.0.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
}


implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'


implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.0.0'


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You need to update the plugin in your root build.gradle to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'`

Comment: Thank you, I modified it, and now it shows me a new error when I sync or clean project: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your dependency is having different version of `com.google.android.gms`.

I inspected `com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3` from [github page](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/build.gradle). I found that it is using very old version of maps, see on above page.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
}
```

As solution you can

1. Either downgrade your play-service dependency versions as same as **maps-utils**
2. Or you can upgrade this dependency gms version by downloading from github page, and add as module in your project.

Keep in mind if you use latest version of gms dependencies in your app, then use latest **google-services** in project level `build.gradle`. Like

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

**Edit** 
Use this config to downgrade your version of gms and firebase.

```
def GMS_VERSION = "11.0.4"
def FCM_VERSION = "11.0.4"

dependencies {
// ...
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$GMS_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$GMS_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$GMS_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$GMS_VERSION"

    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.3'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$FCM_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$FCM_VERSION"
}
```

Comment: When I used to upgrade it shows: Could not find com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:11.0.4.

Comment: Knowing that I updated too: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'

Comment: Wait i tell you complete configuration of your app gradle.

Comment: Why do I need to download the module as you suggested in (2.), why don't upgrade the number directly under dependencies?

Comment: I want ask you, why you are using this map util when it is not actively maintained?

Comment: Because if you just upgrade version, may be that library classes get errors, because things get change in newer version. So if you download that as module and change version, you can resolve module errors which get depricated.

Comment: It's an imported project (not created by me), I'm still trying to get it up and running, is it useless? should I comment it out?

Comment: Anyway, I followed your suggestions and upgraded the classpath version, it doesn't show me the early error, now it shows me a new error when I sync or clean project: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

Comment: See edit part, and then run your app, everything should work fine.

Comment: See if you don't use same versions of dependencies, then you are inviting run time crashes or bugs. Even your old issue is resolved, i strongly recommend to use same version as i edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> One of your dependency is having different version of `com.google.android.gms`.

exactly. At Google, they seem to fix it like (old note):

> ```
>   configurations.all {
>       resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
>   }
> ```

So find out the common/latest used version, and then use [`resolutionStrategy.force`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html).